# Updating field in Firebase on click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a table which pulls data from Firebase. Each row within the table has actions which can be clicked to perform a specific function. One of the actions is to simply set the row as completed. There's a field in my firebase database which holds a key of `true` or `false` for a `read` value. I need to be able to click on the icon (a checkmark) and have the value in firebase updated based on the action.

I have the following so far:

```
var myProducts = new Firebase('https://url-to-firebase-db/products');
$scope.products = $firebaseArray(myProducts);

$scope.products = $firebaseArray(ref);
$scope.markCompleted = function markCompleted(product) {
    product.read = !product.read;
    $scope.products.$save(product);
};
```

On the UI end:

```
<tbody ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: 'category'">
    <td>{{ product.category}}</td>
    <td>{{ product.task}}</td>
    <td><img class="user" src="{{ product.user }}"></td>
    <td>{{ product.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.due | date:'MMMM dd' }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.notes }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.read }}<a class="fa fa-check" ng- 
                          click="markCompleted(product)"></a>
    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm not sure how to trigger the action to update the field in Firebase though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a method that takes in a `product`, and specify it in your template:

```
<tbody ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: 'category'">

    <td>
      <button class="fa fa-check" ng-click="markCompleted(product)" >   
      </button>
    </td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then in your controller you can change the `product.read` value, and save it using a `$firebaseArray`:

```
$scope.products = $firebaseArray(ref);
$scope.markCompleted = function markCompleted(product) {
  product.read = !product.read;
  $scope.products.$save(product);
};
```

Comment: I can see where this is headed, but it's still not pushing the change to firebase. I have included in my original question, additional code to show how I have my firebase array declared.

Comment: Let me take a look, I'll post another example in a bit.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr of this problem? Because using `$scope.products.$save(product);` should work.

Comment: Figured out the issue. It was actually with some other JS on the page. Thanks!

Comment: The other problem with this, is that when the row is marked as `false` or "unread", the row is still visible in the table for rows that have been marked read. They should no longer appear in the table of messages that have been read, and only show up in the unread messages. I set the table to filter for those that have been marked read to be switched to read with `filter: read`, and the ones that have not been read to `filter: !read`. How can I get the read messages to move out of the read table and only show in the unread, as they do in the reverse?